# Can't save form data with nodejs POST request?

Tags: node.js, express

I have a basic form on my "Settings" page that lets users edit their profile. I am able to do a GET request to get the user details to populate the form. However, I'm struggling with taking the new changes and saving them to the user object/database. The only error I get is on the webpage that says "Not Found" (this is probably a generic error from the web design template I downloaded). I don't get any errors in my console. It just doesn't save the data to the database to update the user.

settings.js route:

```
    var express = require('express');
    var router = express.Router();
    var passport = require('passport');
    var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
    var User = require('../models/user');

    // GET user
    router.get('/', function(req, res) {

      const vm = req.user;
      res.render('settings', vm);
    });

    // POST changes
    router.post('/', function(req, res) {
      const vm = req.user;
      var name = req.body.name;
      var username = req.body.username;
      var title = req.body.title;
      var password = req.body.password;
      var isCreator = req.body.isCreator;
      var bio = req.body.bio;

      vm.name = name;
      vm.username = username;
      vm.title = title;
      vm.password = password;
      vm.isCreator = isCreator;
      vm.bio = bio;

      vm.save()
        .then(item => {
          res.send("item saved to database");
        })
        .catch(err => {
          res.status(400).send("unable to save to database");
        });
    });

    module.exports = router;

settings.handlebars HTML form at localhost/settings:

    <body class="scroll-assist">
    <div class="main-container">
      {{#if user}}
          <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1">
              <div class="feature boxed bg-secondary">
                  <form class="text-center form-email" action="/" method="post" data-error="There were errors, please check all required fields and try again" data-success="Changes saved!">
                      <h4 class="uppercase mt48 mt-xs-0">Settings</h4>
                      <div class="overflow-hidden">
                          <h6 class="uppercase">
                              Profile
                          </h6>
                          <input type="text" name="email" class="col-md-6" value="{{email}}" placeholder="Email"/>
                          <input type="text" name="username" class="col-md-6" value="{{username}}" placeholder="username" />
                          <input type="text" name="title" class="col-md-12" value="{{title}}" placeholder="Title" />
                          <input type="text" name="password" class="col-md-6" value="{{password}}" placeholder="Password"/>
                          <input type="text" name="password2" class="col-md-6" value="{{password}}" placeholder="Confirm Password" />
                          <textarea name="bio" rows="2" value="{{bio}}" placeholder="Tell your followers who you are!"></textarea>
                      </div>
                      <div class="overflow-hidden">
                          <hr>
                          <h6 class="uppercase">
                              Become a Creator? (this will make your profile public)
                          </h6>
                          <div class="col-sm-12">
                              <p class="mb16">
                                  Enable Creator Profile
                              </p>
                              <div class="checkbox-option text-left">
                                  <div class="inner"></div>
                                  {{#if isCreator}}
                                  <input type="checkbox" name="isCreatorTrue" value="isCreatorTrue" checked>
                                  {{else}}
                                  <input type="checkbox" name="isCreatorFalse" value="isCreatorFalse"/>
                                  {{/if}}
                              </div>
                          </div>
                          <hr>
                      </div>
                      <div class="overflow-hidden">
                          <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
                              <h6 class="uppercase">
                                  How would you describe your work?
                              </h6>
                              <div class="select-option">
                                  <i class="ti-angle-down"></i>
                                  <select name="referrer">
                                      <option selected value="Default">Select An Option</option>
                                      <option value="google">Gaming</option>
                                      <option value="website">Writing</option>
                                      <option value="friend">Music</option>
                                      <option value="friend">Arts and Crafts</option>
                                      <option value="other">Other</option>
                                  </select>
                              </div>
                              <button type="submit">Save Changes</button>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </form>
              </div>
              {{/if}}
            </div>
        </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have set the form's action to `/settings` but the backend POST route is binded to `/` so they don't match.

So, change the form's action or the binding route, so they match and the `save` method can be executed.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I just changed the HTML form to `action="/" method="post"` but I still get the same issue

Comment: Do you see any error in the backend? Can you check if the callback is being executed?

Comment: I don't see any errors in the node console nor in the mongoDB console. It's like it doesn't get executed at all

Comment: Looking at the html I don't see any `submit` nor `button`. How are you sending the form data?

Comment: I'm using a form button. Somehow the html got cut in my initial post. Just updated it. sorry about that

Comment: No clue on what's going on with this info. Your code looks right. If you can provide more output or any log it would be appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for checking it out. All I see in console is `Starting app.js
Server started on port 3000`. Any advice on how to dive deeper into logs? Don't see any errors

Comment: Have a look on https://expressjs.com/en/guide/debugging.html to see how to debug your app.